# Unable to __set() a protected var

Tags: php, class, get, set

I am trying to get the script below on `__set()` to update the `protected` `var`.

I want this variable to be available to everyone, not just for one instance of the class object.

So far I can only get it to work for one instance, not globally.

```
class SessionClass
{

    protected $ssnuid = 11;
    protected $paccid = 11;
    protected $authkey = 11;

    public function __set($name, $value){

        switch ($name) {

            case 'ssnuid':
                $this->$ssnuid = $value;
                echo $ssnuid;
                break;

            case 'paccid':
                $this->$paccid = $value;
                echo $paccid;
                break;

            case 'authkey':
                $this->$authkey = $value;
                echo $authkey;
                break;
        }

    }

    public function __get($name){
        return $this->name;
    }


// END CLASS
} $session = new SessionClass;


$session->ssnuid = 20;

echo $session->ssnuid;
```

How can I achieve this?

*Newb here so please be kind. Thanks.

Comment: `echo $ssnuid;` should be either `echo $value;` or `echo $this->ssnuid;`

Comment: There I want to echo the protected var so I can see whether it was updated. But it wont once anything.

Comment: Ok then, so you need to use `echo $this->ssnuid;` etc. (`echo $ssnuid;` cannot be used, because you are in object context). Also if you had `error_reporting` set up correctly, you would see "Notice: Undefined variable: ssnuid"...

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Thanks.